# SQL Query for Separated Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

please consider below table

ProductCode     Flag    Date
-----------------------------------------
A                        N      01/10/2015
A                        N      02/10/2015
A                        Y      04/10/2015
A                        Y      05/10/2015
A                        Y      12/10/2015
A                        N      13/10/2015
A                        N      15/10/2015
A                        Y      16/10/2015
A                        Y      16/10/2015
A                        Y      17/10/2015
B                        N      01/12/2015
B                        N      02/12/2015
B                        Y      08/12/2015
B                        N      08/12/2015
B                        N      09/12/2015
what could be the SQL query to give me below resultL
ProductCode    Flag     StartDate     End Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------
A                         N       01/10/2015    02/10/2015
A                         Y       04/10/2015    12/10/2015
A                         N      13/10/2015    15/10/2015
A                         Y       16/10/2015    17/10/2015
B                        N       01/12/2015    02/12/2015
B                        Y       08/12/2015    08/12/2015
B                        N       08/12/2015    09/12/2015
Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think no SQL statement alone does this. It's not simply grouped by a thing, but you appear to want to group them based on what came before/what's next. If it were just a combination of ProductCode and Flag _alone_ you could easily pull if off with `MIN()`, `MAX()` on the date field and a `GROUP BY`. But in this case, this won't help.

Comment: Grouping by flag and a difference in row numbers would work. e.g. `row_number() over (order by date) - row_number() over (partition by flag order by date)`. Then you just need the min / max of each group.

Comment: thanks ZLK, your solution was similar to vkp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to assign groups to continuous N and Y flags for each product. Thereafter, it is just a grouping operation on the classified groups.

```
with grps as (    
 select t.*,
-row_number() over(partition by productcode,flag order by dt) 
+ row_number() over(partition by productcode order by dt) grp
from t
) 
select productcode,flag,min(dt) startdate,max(dt) enddate 
from grps
group by productcode,flag,grp
order by 1,3
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/JIX86877)**

Comment: thanks vkp, i just realized that the problem is known as Gaps and Islands.